# Magento Backend Manage Category Not Working

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, categories

I am using Magento 1.9.2.4
I am not getting any error. When I try to Add the sub category, it just freezes [ajax loading image will popup nothing will happen]
When I try other links such as Add Sub Category / Root Category noting happened.

I have checked in console and its showing this error:

http://www.yourdomain.com/index.php/admin/catalog_category/add/key/4d95e53cc2827e11710e42543037df05/store/0/parent/131?isAjax=true

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Please give me any solution. Thanks

Comment: Please help me anyone to solve this issue.

Comment: any body is here please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that you have `addAction` function in your `CategoryController.php` in the Catalog folder in Adminhtml.

Check if there is no other module overriding this function, and if yes then you might have to debug there.

Also check that correct permissions are given, clear cache and it should work.

If it still does not work then install a fresh version, compare modules and debug further.

Comment: hello twinkal. how to check other module is overriding or not.

Comment: i have checked already addAction in CategoryController.php. but its may be error from other module how can check which module is giving this error.

Comment: Have you installed any other modules or have made any changes to the setup? Or is it just the fresh one?

Comment: hi twinkal I have installed module but dont know which module is giving error please help me to solve this.

Comment: Disable all your modules in local and community folder, clear cache and check. If it works then you know that one of the modules that was causing the error is in local or community. One by one enable the modules and keep checking. This is the only way of debugging.

Comment: thanks but how to disable and enable a module can you please give me the code. or in which file I have to do the changes.